# Python - Regex Pattern Priority - multiple groups of digits

Tags: python, regex

my goal is to create a regex capable to handle this digits series:

```
0014 2139 2411
0003 2139 2411
0104 43
022
```

I'm trying to find a way to create a Regex syntax that will return a group of MAX 4 digits separated by space with MAX 3 repetition, giving result priority of full 4 digits match.
For example if I have this text:

```
  0014434 2139 2411
  Some text line... bla bla
  0003 2139 2411
  0003 2039 2411
  0104 43
  xxxx      
  0223423423
```

I'd like the Regex will return: 0003 2139 2411

In this case:

```
001 2139 2411
0003 21
0104 43
```

I'd like Regex to return -> 0003 21

I tryed with `\d{4}` but on first line it founds 3 different match.
Thanks
Regs

#### UPDATE

As per guggested by @Abion, using this:

```
(^\d{1,4}$|^\d{4} \d{1,4}$|^\d{4} \d{4} \d{1,4}$)
```

works exept for a series of 4 char + space:

[image]

Comment: In your second example, why do you expect it to match `0003 21` instead of `001 2139 2411`? That first line looks like it fits your criteria of "max 3 groups with max 4 digits each".

Comment: I think he means MAX 3 digits repetition??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
(^\d{1,4}$|^\d{4} \d{0,4}$|^\d{4} \d{4} \d{0,4}$)
```

Using group conditionals, this pattern matches a digit group of one to four digits OR a digit group of four digits followed by a digit group of one to four digits OR two digit groups of four digits followed by a digit group of one to four digits. These criteria would eliminate the first line of your second example (a digit group of three digits followed by more digit groups) causing it to match the second line.

Note, you must provide the `re.MULTILINE` option for this pattern to work.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/H3vKJX/2

Comment: Thx @Abion47, seems to works pretty fine exept case where there are 4 digits + space character: seems not to be identified in the pattern. pls see my update. thx

Comment: @user3925023 I was not aware the space was necessary. It's added easily enough though, by changing the second and third conditions' last group to match `{0,4}` instead of `{1,4}`. See the edit.